# how to prevent or handle " javax.microedition.media.MediaException: AUD" when playing audio files in j2me

Tags: java-me, midp-2.0, cldc, nokia-s40, series-40

I'm developing a mobile app in j2me with configuration **cldc2.1 and midp 2.0**.

In my app, I'm running some audio files based on some user operations. But some times audio files running correctly but sometimes it throws  " javax.microedition.media.MediaException: AUD" exception.

I placed the audio files (.wav) in "res" folder of my project and read from that folder and then I'm playing it.

I'm using nokia c2-01 phone (s40) device is for testing. Please give your ideas to solve this problem.

Please help me. All your ideas are welcome.

Comment: When the exception is raised, did the app try to play an audio file while another file was already playing?